# Two Checkout page in Magento is it possible?

Tags: checkout, magento-1.9.2.0

Is there any way to create two checkouts in Magento.
Can anyone tell me the procedure or reference link to this?
I have searched on google but I am not getting any result.

Comment: can you please explain your requirement why you need two checkout

Comment: why do you need to have 2 checkout pages !!

Comment: there is subscription page and normal products page in my website. I want to different checkout page for subscription and normal product page.